# Pyspark: add new column derived from other and with time contition

Tags: python-2.7, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have DataFrame #1 with columns A, B, C startyear, endyear With Values:

```
 year  B  C  startyear endyear
 2010  2  A  2012      2014
 2011  2  A  2010      2013
 2013  2  B  ..         ..
 2012  2  C``
```

I want to create a new column called result

```
 df = df.Withcolumn(...)
```

Resutt will take into consideration start and end years to compute mean of B for each year between start and en dates

if start date = 2012
end date = 2014

then result will be the mean of the sum of ( B2012 + B2013+B2014) = 2+2+2/3=2

Some advice ?

Thank you

Comment: Can you add sample output?

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter with two conditions and then use aggregate function to calculate mean.

```
 df =  df.filter((x_df.year >= x_df.start_yr) &  (x_df.year <= x_df.end_yr))
 df.agg({"B":"mean"})
```